# Reading HTML in Node.js

Tags: html, node.js

I'm trying to launch an index.html page with nodejs, but for some reason I keep getting an Application error after I push it to Heroku. Any idea what I have wrong with my code?

```
 #/!/usr/bin/env node

 var express = require('express');

 var app = express.createServer(express.logger());

 app.get('/', function(request, response) {
     var fs = require('fs');
     var buffer = new Buffer();
     response.send(buffer.toString('utc-8', fs.readFileSync("index.html")));
 });

 var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
 app.listen(port, function() {
 console.log("Listening on " + port);
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [`fs.readFileSync()`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options) without specifying any `options`, the return value will already be a `Buffer`, so you shouldn't have to create another.

```
Buffer.isBuffer(fs.readFileSync('index.html'));            // true
typeof fs.readFileSync('index.html', 'utf8') === 'string'; // true
```

And, [`res.send()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send) can handle being given a `Buffer`. It'll actually convert the `String` back to a `Buffer`, anyways.

```
var fs = require('fs');
response.send(fs.readFileSync('index.html'));
```

---

You may also want to set a `Content-Type` so the browser knows it's HTML:

```
var fs = require('fs');
response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
response.send(fs.readFileSync('index.html'));
```

Or, you can also use Express' [`res.sendfile()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendfile), which will manage both parts for you:

```
app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    response.sendfile('index.html');
});
```

---

Though, if the error you're getting mentions `ENOENT`, you may need to affix the path.

`fs` paths will be relative to the [current working directory](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd), which may not be what you expect.

```
response.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
```

Comment: This is great information and was very helpful! I wasn't able to figure out exactly what was wrong - I tried everything you mentioned a bunch of times and it continued to throw the error. Then I tried going back to just doing response.send('Hello World!') and it still threw the error. So I just created a new directory/app and it works!!!

Answer (score 1):

`buffer.toString('utc-8', ...` – typo, should be `utf-8`. But do consider Jonathan’s answer anyway.